# Can two different types of databases be used in a single SqlDataSource?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I've got a Microsoft SQL Database and a MySQL Database that I need to join and put into a GridView.

So far I've been successful using ASP and a SqlDataSource like so

```html
<asp:SqlDataSource 
      ID="mySqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ connectionStrings:cs1 %>" 
      ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT DashName, DashIP1, 
      SNMP_Name, DoesBackup, DashDevType FROM ConfigBackupDevices">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How ever I'm not sure how to join in the second database. Do I need to do this in the code behind or is it possible in asp?

Comment: No you cant use 2 different DB at same time..

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to bind two data sources to one control, but you can use multiple tables in one data source. You can also join tables.

Comment: So should I abandon the SqlDataSource and just make a datatable in code behind with the two databases then bind the datatable to the gridview?

Comment: you can try this link as some people have posted some answers there to see if it helps: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/81295/how-to-bind-two-sqldatasource-in-one-gridview-of-two-differe.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to bind two databases with one sql datasource.

The best option is create either `DataTable` or `DataSet` with desired data using Join to these different databases. then bind the grid using that `DataTable` or `DataSet`.